# Can a Federal District Bank be negative in SOMA shares after interdistrict settlement?

Tags: central-banking, federal-reserve, united-states, euro-area

I looked at publications examining whether the FED interdistrict settlement could apply to the Target-2 system. While most of my questions were answered, I am still left with one big issue I could not answer myself.

During the settlement between the district banks, the debt is canceled by transferring Certificates and SOMA shares. However, usually, the district banks accumulating debt or claims seem to be the same districts over the period of several years (similar to the Target-2 system where Germany has big amounts of outstanding money and Italy's debt grows annually).

**Q:** How is it possible that the district banks are able to pay other district banks SOMA-shares (+ Gold) every year without ever ending up with a negative balance?

- Do they create money in the process of that interdistrict settlement? If so, how is this coordinated within the FED system? Do Federal District Banks with expected debts create more money than other district banks?
- Has this scenario just not been an occurrence yet? What would potentially happen if so?
- Is there some further rebalancing in the FED system I am missing?